# Modal not works, render after setState not works

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I just started work with RN, I trying to work with modal, modal must display image. I use `FlatList` and for displaying modal, I use variable in dataSource array to show, but when i change it in state it not updates, i even tried call this.render() explicitly and removed Url of image, but render not calls, and modal not works.

Here is link to playground https://repl.it/KHLf/8

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the component's state directly in this method

```
setModalVisible(visible, index) {
    var tempjs = this.state.dataSource
    tempjs[index].modal = visible
    tempjs[index].Url = ""
    this.setState({dataSource: tempjs});
}
```

and that is the reason why it is not updating. You can read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

In order to fix it, change that method to

```
setModalVisible(visible, index) {
    const tempjs = this.state.dataSource.map((v,i) => i !== index 
    ? ({...v, modal: false})
    : ({...v, modal : true}));
    this.setState({dataSource: tempjs});
}
```

[Here it is your example working properly](https://repl.it/KHMd/2)

Comment: How does that methods modify state directly? he never writes `this.state.someState = "something else"`